# How to programatically find Manifest options for the Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

How do you find options about an Activity programatically that we declared in the manifest?  For example, I want to know if and what `android:configChanges` or `android:screenOrientation` was set to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PackageManager` to obtain the `ApplicationInfo`, `ActivityInfo`, etc. with the information that you are seeking. `configChanges` and `screenOrientation` are in `ActivityInfo`.